# How to find parcels related to geocoded addresses?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geocoding, arcgis-desktop

I have geocoded a table of addresses (around 200 records) in ArcMap 10.1 and now need to select the parcel polygons that they are related to. Trouble is the geocoded addresses fall outside of the polygon boundaries.

Is there a recommended method to be able to identify the parcels that belong to these addresses?

Comment: I assume you have your own parcel polygon layer that you are trying to compare the points to, correct?  If so, does the parcel layer have an address field that you can compare to the address field in the geocoded table?

Comment: the parcel table does, however, the addresses are formatted differently as far as capitalization and such, so I'm not able to capture them via a join or other method.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of 1 or 2 records from each table?  Or better yet, a small sample subset for us to look at?  You might get better suggestions that way.

Comment: @Craig How different are the addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [standardizing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00260000000m000000) the addresses (address normalization, correction).  The output can be recombined into fields that share the same formatting.  There are also other services that can found if the arcmap version isn't your flavor. From there, the two can be joined. Sounds simple, but it may get complicated.

Two posts I've seen recently on this topic: [Open Source Address Correction / Parser with Fuzzy Matching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22339/open-source-address-correction-parser-with-fuzzy-matching) and [Address Standardizer Options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/address-standardizer-options/19219#19219).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to select the parcels. This won't select the parcels but it might be a close second:
[Spatial Join Nearest Feature by Straight Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000033000000)

Could you make a selection based off of the results of the join?

Answer (score 0):

While Geocoding the addresses, can you offset the points from the street so each point is closer to the real Parcel? For the points that don't intersect a Parcel, applying a Spatial Join to the Closest Parcel may work most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

We have found that when using the X,Y export that the points were always on the street center line, but when using [DisplayX/DisplayY](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-service-output.htm#GUID-D8DE94E9-5E2E-480D-9DE3-2212B9D7350D), they (as documented) are in the parcel (for PointAddress matches, anyway).

Then it's simply a matter of matching your parcel geometry to the lat/long point.